# when does the `render()` method in react get called

Tags: reactjs

As far as I know these are the scenarios when react calls the `render()` method provided `shouldComponentUpdate()` is not implemented.

1. when your component get mounted initially
2. when state got changed using `this.setState()`
3. when your component receives new `props`
4. when `this.forceUpdate()` get called.

Is there any other scenarios that I am missing?

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything.

Comment: Yeah I think you've answered your own question :)

Comment: Basically: (1) On mount and (2) On `prop` or `state` changes.

Comment: ... and on context :-)

Comment: 2 and 3 depends on the implementation of `componentShouldUpdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when context gets changed render gets called

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's one more case I can think of. When parent component is  re-render.

Every time a component is re-render all its children get re-render too. Unless you implement `shouldComponentUpdate` method in the children.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's actually the case *receives new props*. That's what happens when parent components is rendered.